# Create a Counter in Arango Query

Tags: arangodb

I'm trying to create a counter from 1 to n in an Arango query. Basically, I need to group objects by a number in that range, and return the count of the objects in each group. I had hoped creating a for loop would work, but it doesn't seem to be incrementing. I'm unsure about the syntax.

The two loop I've tried are:

```
FOR count IN [0,1,2,3]
```

and

```
FOR count IN 0..12
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are the correct syntax to creating a counter loop.

The reason why it didn't seem to work for me was because I put the return statement containing the count variable in the sub-loop. It works when it is in the outer loop, like so:

```
FOR count IN 0..12
    LET total = COUNT (
        FOR v, e IN OUTBOUND "some-object" GRAPH "some-graph"
            RETURN 1
    )
    RETURN {total: total, count: count}
```